# trouble with AD and profile import

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint

I am involuntary Admin for a MOSS 2007 site.
We use profile import from AD, from two domains:
Mycompany.com and AM.MyCompany.Com

I was looking at the log for the PEOPLE_DL_IMPORT Content source and it has many entries like:

spsimport://?$$dl$$/MyCompany.com/MyCompany.com/MyCompany.com/am.MyCompany.com/MyCompany.com/am.MyCompany.com/MyCompany.com/am.MyCompany.com/am.MyCompany.com/MyCompany.com/am.MyCompany.com/am.MyCompany.com/am.MyCompany.com/MyCompany.com/MyCompany.com/am.MyCompany.com/am.MyCompany.com

It certainly doesn't look right.

Is this normal? What can I do to remedy it ?

Can I start over? There are users already in SP and some of them are in SP groups for permission purposes.

Answer (score 1):

That is not normal. I have had an issue using our development AD that was similar. The profile import ended up taking down the database server eventually.

I recommend turning off the profile import until you have the problem fixed.

Try deleting the connections responsible for "MyCompany.com" and reconfigure. Try and set the "search base" to be as restrictive as useful and introduce a user filter that will limit to only "valid" users.

We have a "user filter" of (&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)((terminationDate=*))).
That prevents us including any of our "terminated" users in the import.

Once you have deleted the profiles rerun a full import and see if there are any errors.

Be aware that running a full import 3X that does not include a user object (by a faulty user filter perhaps) will delete the users profile.